# What is the actual need for aliases and providers in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Good day guys
I am quite new to Laravel and I faced the problem with understanding of the need for aliases and providers which are located in config/app.php file. Also, why ::class is used at the end of each alias and provider like

```
'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,   Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class
```

what if to omit ::class.

Please guys can you explain in simple terms

Comment: ::class it's a way to tell the code to read the actual name of the class and not the class itself. If you had, for example, added `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App` to the header of the file, you would be able to use simply by doing `App::class`, which could, in the future, prevent a lot of replaces in the code, so you would need to replace only the header line. And also, if you don't use `::class` you will have to use a *string fully qualified* for the class name. In my experience, it's terrible to see a string that big every 2 lines of code.

Comment: @Rafael, thank you dude for your perfect explanation. Please can you also explain why need aliases and providers in Laravel and then make it as solution so that I could accept it :)

Comment: Hope that clarifies. :) Some of this documentations will only make sense to you with time. For example, Laravel comes with Eloquent by Default, I'm using Doctrine instead, and for that I had to read and understand a lot about it also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`::class` it's a way to tell the code to read the **actual name** of the class and not the class itself. If you had, for example, added `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App` to the header of the file, you would be able to use simply by doing `App::class`, which could, in the future, prevent a lot of replaces in the code, so you would need to replace only the header line. And also, if you don't use `::class` you will have to use a string fully qualified for the class name.

Well, you might actually not *need* the aliases, but Laravel makes use of them internally for several operations.

According to their [documentation on Facades](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/facades):

> In the context of a Laravel application, a facade is a class that provides access to an object from the container

Which  means that you can access any of the aliases methods statically.

And as of the [documentation on Service Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/providers):

> Service providers are the central place of all Laravel application bootstrapping. In general, registering things, including registering service container bindings, event listeners, middleware, and even routes

Which will then be necessary if you desire specific data to be loaded before anything else happens on the system, registering different services, downloaded components sometimes.

Some of this are invisible for you if you don't have a good practice working with them, some might be necessary if you decide to transform some part of your code into stand-alone modules.

But mainly, the necessity of them is mainly on Laravel side than on the developer, that is, considering how experienced you are with the Framework and(or) Bootstraping/Service Containing.

Comment: sorry dude but please can you also add the explanation of ::class to the solution so it looks better :)

Comment: sure, in a moment

Comment: Good answer @Rafael

Answer (score 3):

adding to @Rafaels answer. regarding the `::class` syntax.

This feature came in php 5.5, So that you dont have to keep your class names in strings. the `Classname::class` will give the full class path

```
use App\Services\Service1\ServiceClass1;

//...
// suppose you want an array of some classes you can use this syntax
public $realation= [
    Serviceclass1::class, // Equivalent to "App\Services\Service1\ServiceClass1"
];
```

from the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name)

> It is possible to use ClassName::class to get a fully qualified name
>   of class ClassName. For example:

Comment: Funny thing though is that I only really started using that after like 6 years working with PHP, never considered how annoying was to write everything in a string before that.

Comment: ha ha, yes, exactly